# Expresión inválida en programa C#

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña aplicación que hace uso de la *API* *VirtualProtect* es la siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace VirtualProtectTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool VirtualProtectEx( IntPtr hProcess, uint dwAddress, int nSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = Process.Start("app.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (VirtualProtectEx(p.Handle, (uint)p.MainModule.BaseAddress, 4096, 0x100, out uint a))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail!");
                p.Kill();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Pero siempre me devuelve los mismos errores:

> ; expected (CS1002) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,97
>
> Invalid expression term ')' (CS1525) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,96
>
> ; expected (CS1002) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,96
>
> Invalid expression term ')' (CS1525) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,95
>
> ; expected (CS1002) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,95
>
> Invalid expression term 'int' (CS1525) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:25,94
>
> ; expected (CS1002) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:30,13
>
> Invalid expression term 'else' (CS1525) - C:\Users\android\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Consol\Consol\Program.cs:30,9

Answer (score 5):

A primera vista, el error le tienes en la llamada al método `VirtualProtectEx`:

```
if (VirtualProtectEx(p.Handle, (uint)p.MainModule.BaseAddress, 4096, 0x100, out uint a))
```

Para un parametro de tipo `out` no puedes pasarle el tipo directamente en la llamada, debes crear la variable que contendrá el parámetro de salida antes:

```
uint a=0;
if (VirtualProtectEx(p.Handle, (uint)p.MainModule.BaseAddress, 4096, 0x100, out a))
 ....
```

Aquí tienes información sobre `out`:[Modificador del parámetro out (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

---

Para completar la respuesta, y como bien indica @SergioParraGuerra en los comentarios, con la versión 7.0 de C# **esa expresión si sería correcta**. A partir de esa versión, se pueden definir los parametros `out` en la misma llamada sin tener que hacerlo previamente.

Comment: Si se usa Visual Studio 2017 (versión 7.0 de C#) la expresión es totalmente válida. Saludos

Comment: en el enlace que has mostrado se indica. Ver `Llamar a un método con un argumento`

Comment: Si,lo se.Tienes toda la razón @SergioParraGuerra. Pero dado el error que le da al OP he supuesto que no usa ni Visual Studio ni C# 7.0 :)

Comment: Eso es, simplemente quería hacer un inciso de que se puede declarar así la variable `out`en el nuevo VS. Un saludo :)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra y te lo agradezco. He editado la respuesta para indicarlo ya que es una buena información que olvidé incluir. Gracias por el comentario